# How do I get all results from my query

Tags: query

I have written some php code and using the class.pagination.php, am able to paginate it based on a max posts per page that I set inside my code. This works great.

However, it is only returning 11 posts and I know that I have 186 posts, 
I am so stuck, any help would be appreciated.

here is my code:

```
   <?php


define  ("WP_USE_THEMES", false);
define  ("MAX_PER_PAGE", 3);

include ("wp-load.php");
include ("pagination.class.php");

//  posts_per_page=-1

$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'any'));
$posts = $query->get_posts();

$sAllTitles   = array();
$sAllDates    = array();
$sAllContent  = array();
$iCount       = 0;

foreach($posts as $post) 
{
       $sAllTitles[$iCount] = $post->post_title;
       $sAllDates[$iCount]  = $post->post_date;
       $sAllContent[$iCount]= $post->post_content;
       $iCount++;
}

$iCount = 0;
foreach($posts as $post) 
{
    $PostData[] = array(
    'PTitle' => $sAllTitles[$iCount],
    'PDate'  => $sAllDates[$iCount],
    'PCont'  => $sAllContent[$iCount],
    );
    $iCount++;
}

?>

<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>BLOG POSTS</title>

<style>

body
{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size   : 12px;
}

h2
{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size   : 18px;
    color       : #3279BB;
}

.InfoText
{
    font-family : Arial;
    font-size   : 14px;
}

.pagination 
{
    clear       : both;
    padding     : 20px 0;
    position    : relative;
    font-size   : 11px;
    line-height : 13px;
}

.pagination span, .pagination a 
{
    display     : block;
    float       : left;
    margin      : 2px 2px 2px 0;
    padding     : 6px 9px 5px 9px;
    text-decoration : none;
    width       : auto;
    color       : #fff;
    background  : #555;
}

.pagination a:hover
{
    color       : #fff;
    background  : #3279BB;
}

.pagination .current
{
    padding     : 6px 9px 5px 9px;
    background  : #3279BB;
    color       : #fff;
}

</style>

</head>

<?php

if (count($PostData)) 
{
    $pagination  = new pagination($PostData, (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1), MAX_PER_PAGE);
    $pagination->setShowFirstAndLast(true);

    $PostPages = $pagination->getResults();

    echo $pageNumbers = '<div class="pagination">'.$pagination->getLinks().'</div>';

    if (count($PostPages) != 0) 
    {
        print("<br/>");

        foreach ($PostPages as $PostArray) 
        {
        print ('<div class=\"post\">');
            print ('<h2>' . $PostArray['PTitle'] . '</h2>');

            print ('<div class=\"InfoText\">' . $PostArray['PDate'] . '</div>');

        print ('<div class=\"entry BlogText\">');
        print ($PostArray['PCont']);
        print ('</div>');

        print ('</div>');
        print ('<br/>');
        }

        print ($pageNumbers);
    print ("<br/><br/><br/>");
    }
}


wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code is a bit of scramble, difficult to follow. Why aren't you using the main query. You can set `posts_per_page` with `pre_get_posts`. If you really need to run a custom query, check how to do it properly with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **posts_per_page** to return all post from the database
 Just little modification in your WP query

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'any','posts_per_page'=>-1));
?>
```

Try with this modification if it works for you.